# How to use svg.js on Observable notebook

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, require, svg.js, observablehq

I started learning to use [Observable](https://observablehq.com) a few days ago.

I can use svg.js version 2.7.1 by using

```
SVG = require("svg.js") // 2.7.1
```

But when I try to use version 3.0.12, this doesn't work.

```
SVG = require("svg.js@3.0.12")
```

The error is

```
SVG = rt: unable to load package.json
```

And when I try to load via url instead:

```
SVG = require("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.12/svg.js")
```

There's an error as well.

```
SVG = rt: invalid module
```

Is it possible to use `svg.js` v3 with Observable?

Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Version 3 of svg.js was published in the svgdotjs namespace. So `require("@svgdotjs/svg.js")` might work

Comment: @Fuzzyma it's still error `SVG = rt: invalid module`

Comment: @Fuzzyma It use `unpkg.com` be default. Here's the doc on `require`. https://observablehq.com/@tmcw/introduction-to-require 

... I don't understand it very well, but maybe you will.

Comment: I am not sure if observable can resolve esm dependencies. But we export a real module. Maybe its taking the wrong key in the package.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I test `@svgdotjs/svg.js` with the [Module require debugger](https://observablehq.com/@tmcw/module-require-debugger), and eventually find the solution

```
SVG = (await import('https://unpkg.com/@svgdotjs/svg.js?module')).SVG
draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size('100%', 100)
```